# Batch fork bomb?

Tags: batch-file, fork, pipeline

I was looking at the fork bomb on Wikipedia, and the batch examples were:

```
%0|%0
```

OR

```
:here
start ''your fork bomb name''.bat
goto here
```

OR

```
:here
start %0
goto here
```

I understand the second two, they start another instance of themselves and then repeat, but I don't understand the first. I read that the pipeline executes the file to the right with the output of the file to the left. Why can't the fork bomb just be:

```
%0
```

I would assume that this would call itself, but then terminate instantly, but why wouldn't `%0|%0` also terminate? Even though the new instance is going to keep making new instances, isn't the first done after starting the second? What makes the first one continue?

edit: Does it loop because none of the instances can terminate until their recursive call is returned? Does this mean it only ever calls the first `%0`?